# Error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" Despite column match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for troubleshooting.

I work for a small company and we are building a new application. I have the insert statement below (with selected static values for testing) that was working until this morning when we started getting error messages from it (we changed nothing about this table).

```sql
INSERT INTO t_el_powertrain
(                
                 [pt_id]
                ,[el_id]
                ,[segment_id]
                ,[continuous_hp]
                ,[intermittent_hp]
                ,[torque]
                ,[torque_rpm]
                ,[eop]
                ,[checked_out]
                ,[create_date]
                ,[created_by]
                ,[update_date]
                ,[updated_by]
                ,[captive]
)
SELECT          1,          --pt_id  
                100000,     --el_id
                5 ,         --segment_id
                5.00,       --continuous_hp     
                5.00,       --intermittent_hp        
                5.00,        --torque
                5,          --torque_rpm
                5,          --eop
                0,          --checked_out    
                GetDate(),  --create_date      
                5 ,         --created_by         
                GetDate(),  --update_date      
                5,          --updated_by
                10
```

Error message:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the table structure (I refreshed the connection right before)

[image: table definition]

It seems pretty clear to me that there should be no issues with the insert statement below. Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting an error here?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: added picture of the error message

Comment: Check for triggers. Including the entire error message (which should indicate the trigger name and the line number) in your question instead of trying to fit it into the title will probably make this clearer quicker.

Comment: also `INSERT INTO t_el_powertrain` is suspect as you may have a table with the same name in a different schema than `dbo`

Comment: but it is from a trigger as @AaronBertrand suspected

Comment: I'm so embarrassed. I cannot believe I did not see that before... Thanks.

Comment: This means the trigger uses "select *" in some fashion - a problem that you should also fix and a bad habit to kick.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Thanks to a quick response from Martin Smith, I realized that I totally overlooked what DB object was throwing the error.

I forgot to update our history mirror table when I added a column a while back.

Solved. Thanks again.